# How to solve tensorflow Conv2DBackpropFilter error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, conda

I have been trying to use `tf-gpu` without success. I installed cuda from anaconda (not sure if that's the problem or the problem is with the coding). The code works correctly without using gpu and installing cuda. But after I install `tf gpu` I get this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Conv2DBackpropFilter: input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth
     [[{{node gradient_tape/sequential/conv2d_10/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropFilter4}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1390]
Function call stack:
train_function
```

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD,Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255, rotation_range=20,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      vertical_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest',
      brightness_range=(0.1,0.9))
validation = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255)
test = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255)

train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('/raw-img/training', target_size=(200,200), batch_size=1,
                                          class_mode='categorical')

validation_dataset = validation.flow_from_directory('/raw-img/validation', target_size=(200,200), batch_size=1,
                                               class_mode='categorical')
test_dataset = test.flow_from_directory('/raw-img/testing', target_size=(200,200), batch_size=1,
                                               class_mode='categorical')
tf.config.experimental.enable_mlir_graph_optimization()

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape=(200,200,3),padding='same'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU( alpha=0.3),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.2),
                                    #
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU( alpha=0.3),
                                     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size= (3,3),padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU( alpha=0.3),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.25),
                                    #
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU( alpha=0.3),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU( alpha=0.3),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.25),
                                    #
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU( alpha=0.3),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU( alpha=0.3),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.25),
                                    #
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU( alpha=0.3),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU( alpha=0.3),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.25),
                                    #

                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU( alpha=0.3),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU( alpha=0.3),
                                    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.2),
                                    #
                                    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                    #
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1024),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU( alpha=0.3),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512),
    tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU( alpha=0.3),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'),

                                    ])
print(model.summary())
rlronp=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',patience=3,verbose=1, factor=0.7)
es=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",patience=15,verbose=1,
                                    restore_best_weights=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.003), metrics=['accuracy'])
model_fit = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_data=validation_dataset,steps_per_epoch=len(train_dataset),validation_steps=len(validation_dataset),callbacks=[rlronp,es])
```

The following are the packages included in my conda environment:

```
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu
abseil-cpp                20210324.2           hd77b12b_0
absl-py                   0.13.0           py39haa95532_0
aiohttp                   3.7.4            py39h2bbff1b_1
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py39h2bbff1b_1
astor                     0.8.1            py39haa95532_0
astunparse                1.6.3                      py_0
async-timeout             3.0.1            py39haa95532_0
async_generator           1.10               pyhd3eb1b0_0
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
blinker                   1.4              py39haa95532_0
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39h2bbff1b_1003
ca-certificates           2021.7.5             haa95532_1
cached-property           1.5.2                      py_0
cachetools                4.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
certifi                   2021.5.30        py39haa95532_0
cffi                      1.14.6           py39h2bbff1b_0
chardet                   3.0.4           py39haa95532_1003
click                     8.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
colorama                  0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
coverage                  5.5              py39h2bbff1b_2
cryptography              3.4.7            py39h71e12ea_0
cudatoolkit               11.3.1               h59b6b97_2
cudnn                     8.2.1                cuda11.3_0
cycler                    0.10.0           py39haa95532_0
cython                    0.29.24          py39hd77b12b_0
decorator                 5.0.9              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
entrypoints               0.3              py39haa95532_0
flatbuffers               2.0.0                h6c2663c_0
freetype                  2.10.4               hd328e21_0
gast                      0.4.0                      py_0
giflib                    5.2.1                h62dcd97_0
google-auth               1.33.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                      py_2
google-pasta              0.2.0                      py_0
grpcio                    1.36.1           py39hc60d5dd_1
h5py                      3.2.1            py39h3de5c98_0
hdf5                      1.10.6               h7ebc959_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       68.1                 h6c2663c_0
idna                      2.10               pyhd3eb1b0_0
importlib-metadata        3.10.0           py39haa95532_0
importlib_metadata        3.10.0               hd3eb1b0_0
intel-openmp              2021.3.0          haa95532_3372
ipykernel                 5.3.4            py39h7b7c402_0
ipython                   7.25.0           py39h832f523_1    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
jedi                      0.18.0           py39haa95532_1
jinja2                    3.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jpeg                      9d                   h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0                      py_2
jupyter_client            6.1.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_core              4.7.1            py39haa95532_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py39hd77b12b_0
krb5                      1.18.2               hc04afaa_0
libclang                  11.1.0          default_h5c34c98_1    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.71.1               h2a8f88b_1
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libprotobuf               3.14.0               h23ce68f_0
libsodium                 1.0.18               h62dcd97_0
libssh2                   1.9.0                h7a1dbc1_1
libtiff                   4.2.0                hd0e1b90_0
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h2bbff1b_0
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markdown                  3.3.4            py39haa95532_0
markupsafe                2.0.1            py39h2bbff1b_0
matplotlib                3.3.4            py39haa95532_0
matplotlib-base           3.3.4            py39h49ac443_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py39h2bbff1b_1000
mkl                       2021.3.0           haa95532_524
mkl-service               2.4.0            py39h2bbff1b_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.0            py39h277e83a_2
mkl_random                1.2.2            py39hf11a4ad_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multidict                 5.1.0            py39h2bbff1b_2
nbclient                  0.5.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbconvert                 6.1.0            py39haa95532_0
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
notebook                  6.4.0            py39haa95532_0
numpy                     1.20.3           py39ha4e8547_0
numpy-base                1.20.3           py39hc2deb75_0
oauthlib                  3.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
olefile                   0.46                       py_0
openssl                   1.1.1k               h2bbff1b_0
opt_einsum                3.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
packaging                 21.0               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandocfilters             1.4.3            py39haa95532_1
parso                     0.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    8.3.1            py39h4fa10fc_0
pip                       21.1.3           py39haa95532_0
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         3
prometheus_client         0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.17             pyh06a4308_0
protobuf                  3.14.0           py39hd77b12b_1
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2
pygments                  2.9.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyjwt                     2.1.0            py39haa95532_0
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd3eb1b0_1
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyqt                      5.12.3           py39hcbf5309_7    conda-forge
pyqt-impl                 5.12.3           py39h415ef7b_7    conda-forge
pyqt5-sip                 4.19.18          py39h415ef7b_7    conda-forge
pyqtchart                 5.12             py39h415ef7b_7    conda-forge
pyqtwebengine             5.12.1           py39h415ef7b_7    conda-forge
pyreadline                2.1              py39haa95532_1
pyrsistent                0.18.0           py39h2bbff1b_0
pysocks                   1.7.1            py39haa95532_0
python                    3.9.5                h6244533_3
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-flatbuffers        1.12               pyhd3eb1b0_0
python_abi                3.9                      2_cp39    conda-forge
pywin32                   228              py39he774522_0
pywinpty                  0.5.7            py39haa95532_0
pyzmq                     20.0.0           py39hd77b12b_1
qt                        5.12.9               h5909a2a_4    conda-forge
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0
rsa                       4.7.2              pyhd3eb1b0_1
scipy                     1.6.2            py39h66253e8_1
send2trash                1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
setuptools                52.0.0           py39haa95532_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
snappy                    1.1.8                h33f27b4_0
sqlite                    3.36.0               h2bbff1b_0
tensorboard               2.5.0                      py_0
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.6.0                      py_0
tensorflow                2.5.0           gpu_py39h7dc34a2_0
tensorflow-base           2.5.0           gpu_py39hb3da07e_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.5.0              pyh7b7c402_0
tensorflow-gpu            2.5.0                h17022bd_0
termcolor                 1.1.0            py39haa95532_1
terminado                 0.9.4            py39haa95532_0
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tk                        8.6.10               he774522_0
tornado                   6.1              py39h2bbff1b_0
traitlets                 5.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
typing-extensions         3.10.0.0             hd3eb1b0_0
typing_extensions         3.10.0.0           pyh06a4308_0
tzdata                    2021a                h52ac0ba_0
urllib3                   1.26.6             pyhd3eb1b0_1
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wcwidth                   0.2.5                      py_0
webencodings              0.5.1            py39haa95532_1
werkzeug                  1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
wheel                     0.35.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py39haa95532_0
wincertstore              0.2              py39h2bbff1b_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.12.1           py39h196d8e1_1
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0
yarl                      1.6.3            py39h2bbff1b_0
zeromq                    4.3.3                ha925a31_3
zipp                      3.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
zstd                      1.4.9                h19a0ad4_0
```

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/enable_mlir_graph_optimization?hl=ru):

> "Note: MLIR-Based TensorFlow Compiler is under active development and has missing features, please refrain from using. This API exists for development and testing only."

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, but you should try to delete the line:

```
tf.config.experimental.enable_mlir_graph_optimization()
```

and see how it runs.

Comment: i've try think happen

Comment: 2021-07-21 22:45:59.397056: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_grad_filter_ops.cc:688 : Invalid argument: Conv2DBackpropFilter: filter and out_backprop must have the same out_depth